# Get Index Location of a Random DataFrame in List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This should be an easy solution but I'm stuck. I have a bunch of DataFrames stored in a list. I need to randomly select one of the DataFrames, but also acquire the list index location of that dataframe and store it in a variable for later use. My attempt currently throws the following error: `"Can only compare identically-labeled " "DataFrame objects"`

I have also used `enumerate()` methods in for loops before, so maybe it could be used to solve this problem as well.

```py
random_df = random.choice(df_list)
random_df_il = cluster_list.index(random_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use enumerate and "unpack" the random choice using:

```
random_df_il, random_df = random.choice(list(enumerate(df_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a choice among the list indexes, then select your df:

```py
ix = range(len(df_list))
i_rand = random.choice(ix)
random_df = df_list[i_rand]
```

You can also directly pick a random integer with `random.randint(0, len(df_list)-1)`.